# „Ausgeschlafen? Ne! Abgebrochen.“

Tags: meaning-in-context

> „Ausgeschlafen? Ne! Abgebrochen.“

What does "abgebrochen" mean here? Is it some kind of a witty remark? I have a feeling as if I'm missing something.

Comment: Can't answer this question without any context. Where did you find this quote? Who said it in which situation?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Actually I was asked this question by an old lady in the morning today "Ausgeschlafen und abgebrochen?" And I didn't really know what to answer. Than I googled this phrase and found [this](http://cms.reformiert-ronsdorf.de/attachments/052_R%C3%B6mer%2013,8-12%20%281.%20Advent%202012%29.pdf) on the internet.

Comment: I _think_ it means did you get to sleep as long as you wanted to, waking up naturally (ausschlafen ~ sleep in) or did you have to get up, literally: abor your sleep? I could be wrong, though, it's not a phrase I am familiar with.

Comment: If it's a pun or a wit, then it's not an obvious one.  I was thinking it could be referring to students who use their studies primarily to sleep long, so if one student is not a student anymore either because he has graduated (asugeschlafen) or dropped out (abgebrochen). But I checked on Google and I found the same source as @stillenat and my reading makes no sense there. In fact, in that piece of writing the phrasing is just plain weird to me.

Comment: It is a witty remark, implying you are still tired, because you _interrupted_ your sleep too soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> „Ausgeschlafen? Ne! Abgebrochen.“

Your quote is similar to an expression that is used in my family and environment (southwest of Germany):

> "Hast du ausgeschlafen oder aufgehört?"

This is based on the two close meanings of *ausgeschlafen haben*: Either you have stopped sleeping because your clock went off or so, or you have slept as long as you wanted. So there are two situations when this expression can be used: You have slept long, then you refer to this as *Ich habe (heute) ausgeschlafen.*
Or it is very early in the morning and everybody is still tired. You are asked *Na, hast du (schon) ausgeschlafen?*. In the latter case the question is equivalent to *Na, bist du (schon) wach?*. Of course, in this case you have not slept long but you are awake, so you have *ausgeschlafen*, in a sense. Jokingly you can then answer *Nee, aber aufgehört/abgebrochen.* So although you are in the second situation, you interpret - as a joke - the meaning of *ausschlafen* as if it was used in the first situation.

Answer (score 7):

The question is something similar as "Have you slept well?" and the answer is "No, I have interrupted my sleep". In German it is a funny answer but just because it is a surprising answer and because both words are similar adjectives: the first refers to the actual condition of the interviewed person (Are you fit?) and the answer refers to the sleep itself.